# How to stop/cancel a task in activity?.runOnUiThread in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, timer

I have created StopWatch function for Android app in Kotlin using Timer class. I am using activity?.runOnUiThread to display the time in the App Bar (not in View). Is there any simple way to stop timer and set it back to 0. Is the multithreading necessary?

Here is my function:

```
   private fun stopwatch(isCanceled: Boolean) {
    val timer = Timer()

    val tt: TimerTask = object : TimerTask() {
        override fun run() {
            num += 1000L
            val runnable = Runnable { setModeTitle(getString(R.string.chipper_title) + TimerUtil.timerDisplay(num)) }
            activity?.runOnUiThread(runnable)
        }
    }

    timer.schedule(tt, 0L, 1000)

    if (isCanceled) {
       //what to implement here, if possible?
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason for having a single function both for starting and for cancelling a timer?

Comment: Good point, appreciate that but still the question is how to cancel/stop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store a resulting `TimerTask` object and later call `cancel()` on it. Something like:

```
private var tt: TimerTask? = null

private fun stopwatch() {
    val timer = Timer()

    tt = object : TimerTask() {
        override fun run() {
            num += 1000L
            val runnable = Runnable { setModeTitle(getString(R.string.chipper_title) + TimerUtil.timerDisplay(num)) }
            activity?.runOnUiThread(runnable)
        }
    }

    timer.schedule(tt, 0L, 1000)
}

private fun cancelStopwatch() {
    tt?.cancel()
}
```

Just make sure not to call `stopwatch()` twice, without first cancelling an already running stopwatch.